# Linking CanExecute method of commands and authorization management

Tags: c#, authorization, icommand

I want to manage permissions to execute commands and view controls and so on.
Therefore I have a class UserAction implementing ICommand interface.

I want to define UserActions available for the UserManagement using one Enum.

For simplifying UserManagement I want to wrap multiple UserActions to UserActivities which permissions are set in a database table.

On runtime I have a Role class which maintains the currently set of permissions (stored as UserActivities), these permissions are likely to change during runtime.

Does anyone know how to manage this CanExecute methods correctly or are there any nice patterns or frameworks meant for this topic?

I did not find a lot about this for now on the net.

Comment: Are you using something like MVVM Light, or just exposing a bool CanExecuteXXX property?

Comment: Im using a more or less custom made framework. It's not designed by me so I have to stick what I have. The canExecute method of the command is consuming a delegate and now I want to add the authorization management. My UserActivity class exposes a boolean flag if this activity is permitted.

Comment: Should be easy enough then; just && it with what you calc already. The pattern here is the CanExecute machinery and its implementation, not how you calc the final bool.

Comment: You are right. The actual implementation is easy enough, the question is more like: How do I get the permission values from my useractivities to the useractoons (implementation of command) the best way? Maybe I have to refactor my question formulation.

Comment: Possibly. I had the impression that your Role class exposed that in some easy way. If you do raise another question - which might be best - make sure you explain how your Role/Permission system works, and ask how to expose permissions should be exposed. Also, show how you're doing at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a whole what you want to achieve is called *externalized authorization management*. You can consider two different approaches:

1. Microsoft provides something called claims-based authorization. You can find lots of tutorials on the topic online. Here's a great [article from 2013](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/leveraging-claims-based-security-in-aspnet-45.aspx).
2. You can also fully externalize (and standardize) your authorization by using XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language which is both an authorization framework as well as a policy language to define your authorization policies. Unfortunately .NET doesn't have XACML built-in so you need to add in an external authorization engine (also called policy decision point or PDP). There are a couple available from Axiomatics or XEngine (on sourceforge).

Comment: Very nice approach, didn't know XACML. I will check, if I can implement this. Thank you